# Is there a way to convert a date field into a different timezone using Painless language?

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone, elasticsearch-painless

Is there a way to convert this code using Painless?
the index have a field named *created*, and the goal is to convert the value to a different timezone, currently it's in UTC.

```
  "aggregations": {
    "dayOfWeek": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "doc['created'].date.setZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(tz)); doc['created'].date.dayOfWeek",
          "lang": "groovy",
          "params": {
            "tz": "Europe/London"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is it working or not? Do you get any errors when running this?

Comment: I think it's working.I don't have *groovy* installed, I only have *painless*. So I'm trying to find a way to do this using *painless*.

Answer (score 2):

after a long long search on google for my own need. 
This works for me (using painless):

```
def myDate = doc['created'].value.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of('Europe/London')); 
myDate.dayOfWeek;
```

I found help on this page:
https://gitlab.kveer.fr/upstream/elasticsearch/commit/81f60652d8c4763b3470d148239c96bcd0c29553

Comment: Awesome! This made my day .. was looking for that for a few days already and finally his snippet worked! Thanks.